# Wifi Bridge Issues

Tags: wireless-networking, xbox360

I just bought a vonets wifi bridge to give internet to my xbox, but the cd provided will not launch and attempting to launch it crashes windows explorer and prevents me from shutting down or restarting. I hate speaking to customer support so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest software from Vonets website.

Comment: I did that and it installed ok but told me there were compatibility issues but I went ahead anyway and now when the program looks for the wifi bridge nothing shows up

Comment: Xbox network settings set to automatic?